# Yaml: How to deserialize a collection?

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I try to parse a Yaml file with `snakeyaml` lib. Here is my yaml file.

```
---
users:   
  - name: Bobby
    status: single
    license: no    
  - name: Timmy
    status: single
    license: no
    available: yes
```

And Java code.

```
public class Users {
    private List<User> users;
    // getters/setters/def constructor have omitted
}
```

User class.

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String status;
    private String license;
    private String available;
    // getters/setters/def constructor have omitted
}
```

My code to parse the content.

```
Constructor constructor = new Constructor(Users.class);
TypeDescription usersDescription = new TypeDescription(Users.class);
profileDescription.putListPropertyType("users", User.class);
constructor.addTypeDescription(usersDescription);        
Yaml yml = new Yaml(constructor);    
Users users = (Users) yml.load(new FileInputStream(new File("/path/file.yaml")));
```

But I got an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" Cannot create property=users for JavaBean=Users(users=null)
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
    users:
    ^
```

How can I fix it?

*PS*

When I try to dump the content with two users I get

```
!!com.project.model.Users
users:
- {}
- {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Users users= (Users) yaml.loadAs(new FileInputStream(new File("/path/file.yaml")), Users.class);
```

instead of:

```
Constructor constructor = new Constructor(Users.class);
TypeDescription usersDescription = new TypeDescription(Users.class);
profileDescription.putListPropertyType("users", User.class);
constructor.addTypeDescription(usersDescription);        
Yaml yml = new Yaml(constructor);    
Users users = (Users) yml.load(new FileInputStream(new File("/path/file.yaml")));
```